# What happens after TLB miss in x86?

Tags: caching, x86, cpu-architecture, tlb, page-tables

I am currently studying how the Page Miss Handler(PMH)/Page-structure cache works after a TLB/STLB miss, and I noticed that my measurements using the perf tool counters produced unexpected results. I benchmarked a program that writes to a 1GB array randomly using different configurations of 2MB and 4KB pages.

The results show a correlation between the L1 TLB/DTLB hits and the runtime, which is contrary to what I expected.
[image: L1 TLB/DTLB results]

I suspect that there might be other TLB/STLB accesses that I did not take into account during the page-walk or while searching in the PDP/PDE/PML4 caches after a TLB/STLB miss..
This is the flow I imagine happens according to my lecture notes :
[image]

How can I determine if this is the case ?

EDIT:

1.Benchmark code : https://gist.github.com/HodBadichi/e08c1039cc22dd97c33cc9ab52fa97c4

2.It was tested over `Haswell Xeon E3` with the following spec AFAIK:

[image: MY CPU TLB SPEC]

Comment: What CPU did you test on?  Many CPUs have fewer TLB entries for 2M pages, but I'd still have expected the total array footprint covered by all the 2M entries to be larger than with just 4k entries. But perhaps STLB hits were much more important than L1dTLB hits and were correlated due to e.g. Sandybridge https://www.7-cpu.com/cpu/SandyBridge.html has 32 L1dTLB entries for 2M largepages, but apparently no L2TLB (STLB) entries for 2M pages.  That changed with Haswell, with the STLB entries able to hold 2M or 4k pages.  Also, can you include or link the test code you used?

Comment: Thank you for your respond !
I included the CPU`s TLB spec and the main part of the benchmark.

Comment: Thank you for including your code but we need a [MCVE]. The code posted is missing the actual benchmarking and tuning (e.g. I don't see where you could set the array to use 2M pages). Anyway, are you sure the random indices have a long enough period? Is `ran[0]` constantly 0 thereby accessing `array[0]` at every iteration of the outer loop? I don't know what `random_seed` does so it's just a hypothesis.